# Working With DataSet in Console Application

Tags: c#, console, dataset

I am used to work in my program with a DataSet and the DataSet designer. I make a lot's of special queries, which are all available in code as a method. In a c# forms program you just drag a DataGridView from the DataSources pane, it creates an instance of the table adapter and you have access to all the queried you made in the designer. (as: this.jackstableadapter.update({parameters}).

My question is, how do you do that in a console program? There is no way to drag something on your form to make an instance of your Table-Adapter. I tried writing it in code, but I couldn’t get it running. Because in a windows form program the designer generates half of the code when working with datasets but I don't know how to replicate it, can someone help me please

Comment: if you are only working with one Table then use a DataTable also there are plenty of working examples on how to do this on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatSet` can be used in Console application, But as you know, there is no UI in here, so you cannot use `DataGridView` and there is no designer as well. So you can run your sql queries with `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` both as you do in your C# backend code. Its nothing different here, same assembly `System.Data.dll` is used. Yes you cannot drag and drop in console application.

Example:

```
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var customersTable = ds.Tables.Add("Customers");
        customersTable.Columns.AddRange("FirstName", "LastName", "Id", "Address");
        customersTable.Rows.Add("Bob", "Sagget", 1, "123 Mockingbird Lane");
        customersTable.Rows.Add("John", "Doe", 2, "1600 Pennsylvanie Ave");
        customersTable.Rows.Add("Jane", "Doe", 3, "100 Main St");


foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            object item = row[column];
            // read column and item
            Console.WriteLine("item ", item );
        }
    }
}
```

You can work with xml as well.